# How are various reasons of asylum seeking in US compared, in terms of their likelihoods of success?

Tags: usa, asylum, chinese-citizens

How are various reasons of asylum seeking (politics, religion, LGBTQ, ...) compared, in terms of their successful likelihoods for immigration to US? From China in particular, or if that is not possible, either from all the other countries outside US  without differentiating which country, or from any other specific country/countries?

The comparison can be based on

- statistics from social studies, or
- experiences of immigration/asylum-related professionals, or
- impressions from news reports or hearsay.

Comment: What has your own research revealed? https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Sorry. The internet access is restricted here. I have done the best of my research on the limited search results, and found no mentioning of success rates.

Comment: Every application is different, and every set of national laws is different as well. I fail to see how this question can result in any declarative answer. I downvoted the question.

Comment: @DavidRecallsMonica well. Excuse my cluelessness due to the information gap with the world outside.  Wish to find the most likely reasons to succeed, given that all of them are applicable. Some said that political asylum requires much more evidence than religious one, and therefore is more difficult. The judgement of each case is also inevitably influenced by the ideologies of the USCIS employee reviewing it. So it seems to make sense that liberal and conservative reviewers may have differences reviewing a LGBTQ asylum case, and a religious one.

Comment: @Ben please read the [Help (https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/help) pages. This site, and other Stack Exchange sites, is not a discussion forum, and does not welcome opinion. What's sought here are declarative answers. I think your enquiry, reasonable and interesting though it is, will not generate declarative answers. If other users agree with me, the question will eventually be closed. If other users agree with you, the question will remain open.

Comment: @DavidRecallsMonica I was asking about statistical data/comparison from studies, experiences or impressions. Differences between individual cases are not expected to be taken into consideration. The origin of country is China, or if not available, all the countries other than US, or any specific country

Comment: @Ben statistical data and comparisons would be OK here; experiences and impressions constitute "opinion," both disfavored content.

Comment: @DavidRecallsMonica statistica data can be obtained from various channels. Study is only one way. Experiences and impressions are others

Comment: Although in many ways this is a vile question, I'm happy for it to remain open because a) it's a question some people are probably thinking about b) I'm happy that such people read my answer.

Answer (score 5):

It's unlikely that those statistics exist, especially not at any official level.

The reason for this is that asylum claims are based on individual circumstances and experience. When officials consider asylum claims they look at the actual persecution or danger the person is under. They are not granted asylum because (for example) they are LGBTQ, or because of their political views, or because of their religion. They are granted asylum because they were threatened with prison, or were kidnapped, or because a mob tried to burn their house. The reason for the danger is secondary. Another person who holds the same views may be in no danger and so not eligible for asylum. This means that officials likely do not even record statistics like this, because they are not relevant.

Even if statistics for the numbers of successful asylum claims existed, they would not tell you the likelihood of success. If it turned out that (for example) there were lots of asylum claims from women's rights workers, that would only prove that lots of women's rights workers were persecuted (and that they had the ability to travel).

If you are trying to attach yourself to a cause or demographic because you think it will get you asylum, then I beg you not to. Not only are you almost certain to fail, but you are also creating impediments for people whose lives and security are genuinely in danger and need a refuge.